# Mutex Matrix of size define in run-time with global access(C language)

Tags: c, matrix, initialization, mutex, global

For purposes of threads accessing a matrix of data, I need a matrix of mutexes that all threads can access to to ensure only one at a time can access certain data (x,y).
I understand there are other options, but what I really need is this.
I tried a global pointer, and when I received the size of the data matrix from the client/user, I allocated the matrix of mutex with said size. Didn't manage to make it work out... Pointers to arrays of arrays... my head explodes.
here is an example of my puny attempts.

```
xthread_mutex ** globalPointer;

void example_init (int x, int y) {

globalPointer = (xthread_mutex_t **)malloc(sizeof(xthread_mutex_t)* x * y);

int i, j;

for(i=0; i<x; i++){

for(j=0; j<y; j++){

globalPointer[i][j] = xthread_mutex_init();
}
}
```

seg fault on the mutex init, why?
I would appreciate it if you could also give a few tips about how to avoid confusion when mixing pointers and arrays. Isn't it all the same underneath?

edit: I apologise for not mentioning but I'm using 'custom' mutexes, xthread_mutex_init(); basically return a pointer to an allocated lock (created using pthread lock)
If you find nothing wrong then I guess my mistake in the those...

/* Return a new, unlocked mutex */

xthread_mutex_t xthread_mutex_init();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
globalPointer = (xthread_mutex_t **)malloc(sizeof(xthread_mutex_t)* x * y);
```

allocates space for `x*y` mutexes. But you can't simply treat that as a `xthread_mutex_t**`, if you have

```
globalPointer[i][j]
```

that interprets the `sizeof(xthread_mutex_t*)` bytes at an offset of `i*sizeof(xthread_mutex_t)` bytes from the start of the allocated memory as a pointer (to a `xthread_mutex_t`).

One way to achieve what you want would be to allocate a one-dimensional array,

```
xthread_mutex_t *real_pointer = malloc(x * y *sizeof *real_pointer);
```

and space for `x` pointers to `globalPointer`,

```
globalPointer = malloc(x * sizeof *globalPointer);
```

and then fill it with pointers into the block pointed to by `real_pointer`,

```
for(int i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
    globalPointer[i] = realPointer + i*y;
}
```

Another option is to allocate space for `x` pointers to `globalPointer` as above, and then `malloc` space for `y` mutexes to each of these pointers in a loop.

Comment: Instead, try this: `xthread_mutex_t (*mutex_matrix_pointer)[x] = malloc(y * sizeof *real_pointer);` or similar. Now you have a real two-dimensional array. However if you want to store it in a global that's not variably-modified, you'll need to cast back to the right type every time you use it.

Comment: Because the types don't match, I didn't mention that option. Otherwise, that's my favourite way.